# Is there a benefit to having multiple package.json files on the same application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am building my very first full react web application from back to front. Up until now, I have been completing a lot of assignments that have been partially created for me.

In my current set up, I noticed that somehow I have a package.json file in both my root directory and my client directory. Is there a benefit to having multiple? Or can I put everything in my root directory?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to you and what you plan to do with your project.  It can be beneficial for production (and debugging) purposes to separate your front- and back-end dependencies.  If you are working on a quick hobby project, there may be little benefit from this separation.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Would I be correct in assuming that dependencies installed in the client folder are not accessible throughout the entire application, but only in the client directory and downward vs. the dependencies in the root being available in all directories?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.  You will need to run `npm i` from each directory to update your project.